# Splitting feature classes into different geodatabases using ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, feature-class

Like another post on here - I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.1 (ModelBuilder) to split feature classes in a geodatabase by an attribute field ("Country").  This process is fine but the issue is exporting these individual feature classes to separate geodatabases (using Feature Class Iterator).

I want to copy these split "country" feature classes, copy these separate features to a geodatabase with the same "Country" name - the result to be separate country geodatabases with a single country inside.

So far with the site model below - I can make a split the site feature classes by country into a geodatabase and can create separate "Country" geodatabases using the iterator - but fail to copy the feature classes into these.

Can someone provide me step-by-step directions to solve this issue?

[image: Complete Model]

Comment: Please provide a link to the post you refer to when you say "Like another post on here".  Please only ask one question per question.  At which of your steps are you stuck?  If it's the one in your first question then that should be your question.

Answer (score 1):

Everything flowing into the iterator needs to run once. But as EVERYTHING runs as many times as an iterator loops then EVERYTHING is running...

Not what you want. The iterator and everything downstream of it needs to be in its own model and that sub-model connects to the output of the split by attribute.

You could look at a help file or search this site for sub-models.

Comment: This makes the model look tidier but the same output is produced where the output is of Geodatabases with the same names as the Feature Classes.

Comment: There is still the same problem - this model creates the correct Geo databases but does not copy the files into those newly created containers

Comment: @Tom You need to update your question and show how you have altered the model.